jdeveloper 12.2.1.4 OSB new application disable
I have a problem in jdeveloper 12C (12.2.1.4.0) into a Orale Virtual Box 6.1
The new application button is disable, what is the reason? , what ca i do to enable it?
I can view and edit pipelines and others about OSB, no problem with that.
Thanks in advance.

Virtual Box:

OSB 12.2.1.4


I backed up the AppData/Roaming/JDeveloper folder and starting jdeveloper again solved the problem.
Action to resolve:

Problem solved:

